# Full join in two columns with repeated values

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, where-clause, outer-join

I have two tables that look like this:

sMinMax:

```
PartNo  baseID  Min   Max  
11795   1       1     1
11795   5       0     0
11795   6       1     1
01655   65      2     3
```

vsStock:

```
PartNo  baseID  Qty
11795   1       1
11795   1       1
11795   55      1
```

I would like to join them so I get a table that shows all the columns together for all the parNo en bases like this:

result:

```
PartNo  baseID  Min   Max  Qty
11795   1       1     1     2
11795   5       0     0     null
11795   6       1     1     null
11795   55      null  null  1
01655   65      2     3     null
```

So I would just do this with a full outer join on two columns but this gives the same results that I would expect from a left join. I tried 1000 things but this is my last try:

```
SELECT 
 a.sPart_ID
,a.uRALBase_ID
,a.MinQty
,a.MaxQty
,b.Qty

FROM [RALNHVTST].[dbo].[sMinMax] as a

FULL OUTER JOIN [RALNHVTST].[dbo].[vsStockList] as b

ON a.sPart_ID = b.sPart_ID
AND a.uRALBase_ID = b.uRALBase_ID
WHERE a.sPart_ID IS NOT NULL
AND a.sPart_ID = 1159

ORDER BY a.sPart_ID
```

but as I said this gives me the same results as a LEFT JOIN. Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The WHERE clause conditions make the FULL OUTER JOIN return LEFT OUTER JOIN result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that? This query gives me same result as you expected.

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN a.PartNo IS NOT NULL THEN a.PartNo ELSE b.PartNo END AS PartNo
,CASE WHEN a.baseId IS NOT NULL THEN a.baseId ELSE b.baseId END AS baseId
,a.[Min]
,a.[Max]
,SUM(b.Qty) AS Qty

FROM [dbo].[sMinMax] as a

FULL JOIN [dbo].[vsStock] as b

ON a.partNo = b.partNo
AND a.baseId = b.baseId
GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN a.PartNo IS NOT NULL THEN a.PartNo ELSE b.PartNo END, 
    CASE WHEN a.baseId IS NOT NULL THEN a.baseId ELSE b.baseId END, 
    a.[Min],
    a.[Max]
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN a.PartNo IS NOT NULL THEN a.PartNo ELSE b.PartNo END
```

Comment: Little follow up question:
What would the code look like if I'd like to add a LEFT JOIN to add the description of the part? Like this:

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[sPart] as c
on a.PartNo = c.ID

Comment: I would use OR expression between two comparsions. Something like JOIN [dbo].[sPart] AS c ON c.Id = a.PartNo OR c.Id = b.PartNo.
And please, if you are ok with my answer, mark that as right solution.

Comment: @CathalClavie . . . This does not implement the filtering in your question, so I don't see how it is "perfect".

Comment: @GordonLinoff . . . To be honest, I was not inspecting query from question, I just looked at source data and expected result. But it's not hard to implement some WHERE condition into my solution, for example WHERE CASE WHEN a.baseId IS NOT NULL THEN a.baseId ELSE b.baseId END = 1159.

Comment: @OndřejCrha . . . It is challenging to filter `full join`s.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering in a `full join` is tricky.  I would recommend filtering and aggregating in subqueries:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sm.sPart_ID, s.sPart_Id) as sPartId,
       COALESCE(sm.uRALBase_ID, sm.uRALBase_ID
       sm.MinQty, sm.MaxQty, s.Qty
FROM (SELECT sm.*
      FROM [RALNHVTST].[dbo].[sMinMax] sm
      WHERE sm.sPart_ID = 1159
     ) sm FULL OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT s.sPart_ID, s.uRALBase_ID, SUM(qty) as qty
      FROM [RALNHVTST].[dbo].[vsStockList] s
      WHERE s.sPart_ID = 1159
      GROUP BY s.sPart_ID, s.uRALBase_ID
     ) s
     ON sm.sPart_ID = s.sPart_ID AND
        sm.uRALBase_ID = s.uRALBase_ID
ORDER BY sPart_ID
```